# emojioneArea is't a function in ionic.bundel javascript

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have imported emojioneArea.js and emojioneArea.css files in ionic, cordova and angularJs project.

I am getting  emojioneArea is't a function in ionic.bundel javascript

But in plan html i was imported both,It was working

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvNRL.png)

```js
$("#chatBox").emojioneArea({
      pickerPosition : "top"
    })
```

```html
<link href="../emoji/emojionearea.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../emoji/emojionearea.js"></script>


<label class="item-input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" id="chatBox" placeholder="Type your message" on-return="sendChatMessage(); closeKeyboard()" on-focus="inputUp()" on-blur="inputDown()" />
        </label>
```

Comment: Is this your solution to the problem? Or did you mean post this as an edit to your question?